Quantifying stable part of ODE
Currently leanring about linear time-invariant (LTI) systems and certain measures of stability, and was quite fascinated by the role that eigenvalues play in determining the stability of the system. As far as I understand, if a linear ODE system described by
$$\dot{x}(t) = A x(t)$$
has eigenvalues of $A$ whose real parts are all negative then the system is stable. If there is a positive eigenvalue (no matter how small)) then the system is asymptotically unstable. I was just curious then, as to what the interpretation of a function we can call $S$ is, if
$$S = \sum_{\lambda \in X }\lambda_i$$
where $X = \{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n \mid \Re(\lambda)<0\}$, i.e $S$ is the sum of all real parts negative eigenvalues? Does this serve as an adequate quantifier of stable part of the system? and if so, what does it mean/really measure in relation to other things?

The measure of order/chaos I think you want is the Lyapunov Exponent

This is an interesting question. To give a comprehensive answer, we need to introduce first that the signed volume of the $n$-dimensional parallelepiped
$$
P(v):=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i:a\in[0,1]^n\right\}
$$
defined by the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, denoted by $\mathrm{vol}(P(v))$ is given by
$$
\mathrm{vol}(P(v))=\det(A),
$$
where $A$ is the matrix having the $v_i$'s as columns; i.e. $A=[v_1\ v_2\ \ldots\ v_n]$.
Now, observe that we have that $x(t)=\Phi(t)x(0)$, where $\Phi(t):=\exp(At)$ describes how the state evolves over time. The signed volume associated with the parallelepiped defined by the columns of $\Phi(t)$ is given hence by $\det(\Phi(t))$ and, by virtue of Jacobi identity we have
$$
\det(\Phi(t))=\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_it\right),
$$
where the $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.
So, one can observe that the rate of convergence of the volume is given by $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$. If this quantity is negative, then the volume exponentially converges to zero and this may still happen whenever there are some eigenvalues with positive real part.
In any way, we can now restrict the dynamics of the system on the stable manifold, that is the restriction of the system to the space spanned by the eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalues with negative real part. This system writes
$$
\dot{z}(t)=VAWz(t)
$$
for some matrices $V$ and $W$, and the matrix $VAW$ of the restricted system contains all the stable eigenvalues of $A$ with the same eigenvectors. If we apply now the same discussion as before, we get
$$
\det(\exp(VAWt))=\exp\left(St\right)
$$
where $S$ is defined as in the post. This shows that the quantity $S$ defines the rate of convergence of the parallelepiped defined by the column of the fundamental matrix of the system $\dot{x}=Ax$ restricted to its stable manifold.
